# create pdf from word WITHOUT libreoffice

Tags: shinyapps, officer

I'm using officer to create a word document in an application deploy through shinyapps.
That discards the use of libreoffice, the "install and define the path" thing.

So, is there a way to create pdf from docx without the need of libreoffice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you can only create pdf from docx with libreoffice or with Word. It's implemented in package doconv (https://cran.r-project.org/package=doconv).

Maybe there are solutions with some external web services (but I think you will have to pay a license) but nothing implemented as FOSS.

With shinyapps, only the second one seems possible right now.